# Delete shortcut from remote computers with multiple users

Tags: vbscript

***Warning I have zero VB knoeledge***

So I found this handy script this morning:

```
InputFile = "C:\MachineList.Txt"
Const DeleteReadOnly = True
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(InputFile)
Do While Not (objFile.AtEndOfStream)
strComputer = objFile.ReadLine
On Error Resume Next
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
objFSO.DeleteFile("\\" & strComputer & "\c$\Documents and Settings\all users\Desktop\Malwarebytes Anti-Malware.LNK")
Err.Clear
Loop

MsgBox "Done"
```

It did the job great. The problem I am facing is the shortcut is not always under all users or their name lets call it user1

So I would love for it to go through MachineList.txt and browse through all of the profiles searching for Malwarebytes Anti-Malware.LNK. I have seen a few scripts on this but I just cannot wrap my head around VB is a short amount of time. I appreciate any input.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that what you provided results in valid paths... therefore this should work:

```
InputFile = "C:\MachineList.Txt"
Const DeleteReadOnly = True
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(InputFile)
Do While Not (objFile.AtEndOfStream)
    strComputer = objFile.ReadLine
    For Each objsubfolder In objFSO.GetFolder("\\" & strComputer & "\c$\Documents and Settings\").subfolders
        If objFSO.FileExists(objsubfolder.Path & "\desktop\Malwarebytes Anti-Malware.LNK") Then
            objFSO.DeleteFile (objsubfolder.Path & "\desktop\Malwarebytes Anti-Malware.LNK")
        End If
        'To check another file uncomment this
        'Add as many of these as you like here
        'If objFSO.FileExists(objsubfolder.Path & "\desktop\Otherfile.LNK") Then
        '    objFSO.DeleteFile (objsubfolder.Path & "\desktop\Otherfile.LNK")
        'End If
    Next
Loop

MsgBox "Done"
```

Comment: Ignore that above

That works!  Thanks a ton.  Would I need to create a new script to add, cCleaner.LNK and Chrome.LNK?

I tried to add the lines under malware bytes but I get:

Script:  C:\users\myname\desktop\testing.vbs
Line:    13
Char:    5
Error    Unexpected 'Next'
Code:    800A041F

Comment: You'd just need to add another if objFSO.FileExists... objFSO.DeleteFile... End if for each additional file. I edited my answer to make it obvious what I mean.